# Unit testing classes inheriting abstract class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class like that:

```
public abstract class Field<T>
{
    private int _length;
    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return _length;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (value <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The length must be greater than 0");
            }
            else
            {
                _length = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private T _value;
    public T Value 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_value == null) throw new ArgumentException("Field does not have any value set");
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            //here obviously I have some code to check the value and assign it to _value
            //I removed it though to show what the problem is

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public Field(int length, T value)
    {
        Length = length;
        Value = value;
    }

    public Field(int length)
    {
        Length = length;
    }

    //some abstract methods irrelevant to the question...
}
```

Then I have a class that inherits Field<>

```
public class StringField : Field<string>
{
    public StringField(int length, string value)
        : base(length, value)
    { }

    public StringField(int length)
        : base(length)
    { }

    //implementation of some abstract methods irrelevant to the question...
}
```

When I run a test like this, it is fine and passes (constructor throws a correct exception):

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))]
public void Constructor_LengthOnly_LengthZero_ShouldThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
{
    int length = 0;
    StringField sf = new StringField(length);

    //should throw exception
}
```

But when I run this test, the constructor does not throw, even though it should throw NotImplementedException:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(NotImplementedException))]
public void Constructor_LengthAndValue_ValidLength_TextTooLong_ShouldThrowNotImplementedException()
{
    int length = 2;
    string value = "test";

    StringField sf = new StringField(length, value);

    //should throw exception
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? I don't think I am missing something, am I? Thanks.

--EDIT--

Turns out everything was ok, here what was happening:
- in the `Field` I had another property and constructor like so:

```
enprivate string _format;
public string Format 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return _format; 
    }
    protected set
    {
        _format = value;
     }
}

public Field(int length, string format)
{
    Length = length;
    Format = format;
}
```

- since the derived class was replacing `T` with `string`, I thought that by calling the base like I showed in my original message, I am calling the constructor that takes `Value`, but I was calling the one taking `Format`...
- to fix this, in my `StringField` class I replaced a call to the base constructor to look like this:

```
public StringField(int length, string value)
    : base(length, value: value)
{ }
```

An intresting case of type conflicts while using generics :)

Comment: Your code works fine for me, look your build log, maybe your dll is used by other process

Comment: I updated my answer as I have found an issue and solved the problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted you code, and for me the test executes as expected: the code throws a new NotImplementedException() and the test is Passed.

Perhaps you are executing some old dll:s? Or that some of the code before the "throw new NotImplementedException()" is causing the problem? Can you post those lines of code?

Comment: The exception I posted in my original post is a first line of the setter. so I guess it must be old dll's, strange that I cleaned and rebuilded and still get this...